# How to convert a nested list into data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

Following is the nested list and I want to convert it to data.table.

```
list(list(symbol = "AAPL210212P00065000", description = "AAPL Feb 12 2021 $65.00 Put", 
    exch = "Z", type = "option", last = 0.01, change = 0, volume = 0L, 
    open = NULL, high = NULL, low = NULL, close = NULL, bid = 0, 
    ask = 0.01, underlying = "AAPL", strike = 65, greeks = list(
        delta = 0, gamma = -1.09695e-14, theta = -0.00308333, 
        vega = 2e-05, rho = 0.00713933, phi = -0.0149899, bid_iv = 0, 
        mid_iv = 1.199176, ask_iv = 2.39835, smv_vol = 0.619, 
        updated_at = "2021-02-08 20:56:01"), change_percentage = 0, 
    average_volume = 0L, last_volume = 1L, trade_date = 1612544837252, 
    prevclose = 0.01, week_52_high = 0, week_52_low = 0, bidsize = 0L, 
    bidexch = "J", bid_date = 1612817742000, asksize = 0L, askexch = "H", 
    ask_date = 1612857600000, open_interest = 28L, contract_size = 100L, 
    expiration_date = "2021-02-12", expiration_type = "weeklys", 
    option_type = "put", root_symbol = "AAPL"), list(symbol = "AAPL210212C00065000", 
    description = "AAPL Feb 12 2021 $65.00 Call", exch = "Z", 
    type = "option", last = 70.53, change = 0, volume = 0L, open = NULL, 
    high = NULL, low = NULL, close = NULL, bid = 71, ask = 72.75, 
    underlying = "AAPL", strike = 65, greeks = list(delta = 1, 
        gamma = -1.09695e-14, theta = -0.00308333, vega = 2e-05, 
        rho = 0.00713933, phi = -0.0149899, bid_iv = 0, mid_iv = 1.658792, 
        ask_iv = 3.31758, smv_vol = 0.619, updated_at = "2021-02-08 20:56:01"), 
    change_percentage = 0, average_volume = 0L, last_volume = 5L, 
    trade_date = 1612795977049, prevclose = 70.53, week_52_high = 0, 
    week_52_low = 0, bidsize = 0L, bidexch = "Q", bid_date = 1612857600000, 
    asksize = 0L, askexch = "Q", ask_date = 1612857600000, open_interest = 7L, 
    contract_size = 100L, expiration_date = "2021-02-12", expiration_type = "weeklys", 
    option_type = "call", root_symbol = "AAPL"))
```

Currently, I am using the following code for conversion, but the class information is lost while doing the conversion and all columns turn into characters.

```
library(plyr)
plyr::rbind.fill(lapply(lst,function(y){as.data.frame(t(unlist(y)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)})) %>% as.data.table
```

Is there a way to flatten this list so that class information is retained as well?

I do not want to use a `plyr::rbind.fill` function to flatten the list as it is slow.
I tried using the `data.table::rbindlist` function but some of the nested list's information is lost.

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(d, use.names=TRUE, idcol = "ID")
```

Thanks for the solutions! Here are the results of both solutions given below -

```
>           microbenchmark::microbenchmark(tibblify =as.data.table(tibblify(lst)),
+                                                           rrapply = as.data.table(rrapply(lst, f = function(x) ifelse(is.null(x), NA, x), how = "bind")), times = 100)
Unit: milliseconds
     expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 tibblify 23.018137 27.082619 32.579234 29.164100 31.895398 116.16178   100   b
  rrapply  1.522039  1.901585  2.599128  2.224162  2.866303  21.86894   100  a
```

Thanks!

Comment: The issue with all being convert to characters, is due to using `t` - this is a matrix function, and matrices differ from data.frames (and data.tables) by only allowing 1 data type (character, integer, logical, etc.). And character is the most common data type.

Comment: For clarity, it isn't that `character` is the most *common* data type, it's the highest (or lowest) data type present. That is, if there are 99 `integer`s and only one 1 `numeric`, it's converted to `numeric`; 99 ints and 1 `character`, then `character` wins. `logical` < `integer` < `numeric` < `complex` < `character`, and there's a hint of `POSIXt` and `Date` before `numeric`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use `rrapply()` in the `rrapply`-package, which also unnests deeper nested layers by default (see e.g. `greeks`):

```
library(rrapply)

rrapply(lst, how = "bind")
#>                symbol                  description exch   type  last change
#> 1 AAPL210212P00065000  AAPL Feb 12 2021 $65.00 Put    Z option  0.01      0
#> 2 AAPL210212C00065000 AAPL Feb 12 2021 $65.00 Call    Z option 70.53      0
#>   volume open high  low close bid   ask underlying strike greeks.delta
#> 1      0 NULL NULL NULL  NULL   0  0.01       AAPL     65            0
#> 2      0 NULL NULL NULL  NULL  71 72.75       AAPL     65            1
#>   greeks.gamma greeks.theta greeks.vega greeks.rho greeks.phi greeks.bid_iv
#> 1 -1.09695e-14  -0.00308333       2e-05 0.00713933 -0.0149899             0
#> 2 -1.09695e-14  -0.00308333       2e-05 0.00713933 -0.0149899             0
#>   greeks.mid_iv greeks.ask_iv greeks.smv_vol   greeks.updated_at
#> 1      1.199176       2.39835          0.619 2021-02-08 20:56:01
#> 2      1.658792       3.31758          0.619 2021-02-08 20:56:01
#>   change_percentage average_volume last_volume   trade_date prevclose
#> 1                 0              0           1 1.612545e+12      0.01
#> 2                 0              0           5 1.612796e+12     70.53
#>   week_52_high week_52_low bidsize bidexch     bid_date asksize askexch
#> 1            0           0       0       J 1.612818e+12       0       H
#> 2            0           0       0       Q 1.612858e+12       0       Q
#>       ask_date open_interest contract_size expiration_date expiration_type
#> 1 1.612858e+12            28           100      2021-02-12         weeklys
#> 2 1.612858e+12             7           100      2021-02-12         weeklys
#>   option_type root_symbol
#> 1         put        AAPL
#> 2        call        AAPL
```

NB: compared to e.g. `tibblify()`, `rrapply()` tends to be more efficient:

```r
library(tibblify)
library(data.table)

## create a large nested list 
lst_large <- do.call(c, replicate(1E5, lst, simplify = FALSE))

system.time({
  as.data.table(rrapply(lst_large, how = "bind"))
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   4.882   0.143   5.026

system.time({
  as.data.table(tibblify(lst_large))
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>  45.954   0.016  45.980
```

---

**Edit:** to avoid ending up with list-columns in the data.frame/data.table due to elements that are `NULL`, an option is to first replace the `NULL` values by `NA` before unnesting the list,

```r
res <- rrapply(lst, f = function(x) ifelse(is.null(x), NA, x), how = "bind")
str(res)
#> 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  45 variables:
#>  $ symbol           : chr  "AAPL210212P00065000" "AAPL210212C00065000"
#>  $ description      : chr  "AAPL Feb 12 2021 $65.00 Put" "AAPL Feb 12 2021 $65.00 Call"
#>  $ exch             : chr  "Z" "Z"
#>  $ type             : chr  "option" "option"
#>  $ last             : num  0.01 70.53
#>  $ change           : num  0 0
#>  $ volume           : int  0 0
#>  $ open             : logi  NA NA
#>  $ high             : logi  NA NA
#>  $ low              : logi  NA NA
#>  $ close            : logi  NA NA
#>  $ bid              : num  0 71
#>  $ ask              : num  0.01 72.75
#>  $ underlying       : chr  "AAPL" "AAPL"
#>  $ strike           : num  65 65
#>  $ greeks.delta     : num  0 1
#>  $ greeks.gamma     : num  -1.1e-14 -1.1e-14
#>  $ greeks.theta     : num  -0.00308 -0.00308
#>  $ greeks.vega      : num  2e-05 2e-05
#>  $ greeks.rho       : num  0.00714 0.00714
#>  $ greeks.phi       : num  -0.015 -0.015
#>  $ greeks.bid_iv    : num  0 0
#>  $ greeks.mid_iv    : num  1.2 1.66
#>  $ greeks.ask_iv    : num  2.4 3.32
#>  $ greeks.smv_vol   : num  0.619 0.619
#>  $ greeks.updated_at: chr  "2021-02-08 20:56:01" "2021-02-08 20:56:01"
#>  $ change_percentage: num  0 0
#>  $ average_volume   : int  0 0
#>  $ last_volume      : int  1 5
#>  $ trade_date       : num  1.61e+12 1.61e+12
#>  $ prevclose        : num  0.01 70.53
#>  $ week_52_high     : num  0 0
#>  $ week_52_low      : num  0 0
#>  $ bidsize          : int  0 0
#>  $ bidexch          : chr  "J" "Q"
#>  $ bid_date         : num  1.61e+12 1.61e+12
#>  $ asksize          : int  0 0
#>  $ askexch          : chr  "H" "Q"
#>  $ ask_date         : num  1.61e+12 1.61e+12
#>  $ open_interest    : int  28 7
#>  $ contract_size    : int  100 100
#>  $ expiration_date  : chr  "2021-02-12" "2021-02-12"
#>  $ expiration_type  : chr  "weeklys" "weeklys"
#>  $ option_type      : chr  "put" "call"
#>  $ root_symbol      : chr  "AAPL" "AAPL"
```

Comment: Thanks, @Joris! I applied ```dt = rrapply(lst_large, how = "bind")``` on the data provided in question. However, after running ```str(dt)```, I am seeing that some of the of the coloums got converted to ```list``` type even after using ```as.data.table```. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: I have confirmed, ```rrapply``` is much faster than ```tibblify```. The only problem is it keeps few column types as list.

Comment: The columns that cannot be converted to vectors are the columns containing `NULL` values (open, high, low, close). The same columns also remain list-columns with `as.data.table(tibblify(lst))`, so the behavior is the same.

Comment: See the edited question, you could replace the `NULL`'s by something else (e.g. `NA`) before unnesting to avoid ending up with list-columns.

Comment: Thanks for handling NULLs. ```rrapply``` is much faster than ```tibblify```. I have shared the results in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

`tibblify` it first and then convert it to data.table:

```
library(data.table)
library(tibblify)

as.data.table(tibblify(lst))
```